# Delete and reinstall hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, reinstall

I have already installed and worked in hyperledger fabric in ubuntu 16.04 and somehow i deleted the packages. I want to reinstall it again and working but it always showing up the error in first-network itself.

So can anyone suggest me how to start over it from the first?

Comment: just ./byfn down and up. What are you missing exactly? Fabric samples?

Comment: Yes i have tried. But while doing ./byfn up, I am receiving error like this
got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'mychannel': error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: proposed update requires that key [Group]  /Channel/Application/Org1MSP be at version 0, but it is currently at version 1. I have cleared docker images and tried, nothing works. How to resolve this?

Comment: Appears that your previous data was not deleted.  Did you run `./byfn down` first?

Comment: Yes I did, and it shows 
---- No containers available for deletion ----
---- No images available for deletion ----

Comment: I tried removing all containers and images, and start all over again. while running ./byfn up, getting error like Error: error getting chaincode bytes: failed to calculate dependencies: incomplete package: github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim. How to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the go.mod and go.sum for the vendored packages, chaincode in 2.0.0 does not include the packages, follow the chaincode structure of go.mod and go.sum like here

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/master/chaincode/marbles02/go

, then execute the following command to vendor the packages,

> go mod download

Answer (score 0):

try pruning the docker volumes and system. Use `docker volume prune -f` and `docker system prune -f`

Comment: Tried this. Though getting the same error "Error: error getting chaincode bytes: failed to calculate dependencies: incomplete package: github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim"

Comment: `go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim`. Assuming you have set GOPATH correctly.